# Batch for loop syntax error despite identical syntax to functional one above

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I somehow have a syntax error on the for loop on line 71 of this batch script despite it seemingly being correct, please help!

```
...
:: Count all files in target dir
:: Only do so on files/folders without "zzz" in name
echo Counting input files...
for /r "%packDir%" %%D in (*.png) do ( (echo "%%D" | find /i "zzz" 1>nul) || set /a filesTotal=filesTotal+1 )
echo Found %filesTotal% input files.
echo.

:: Execute following on each png in dir
for /r "%packDir%" %%D in (*.png) do (
    :: test that for loop above works
    echo lol
...
```

For full context, see [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/H2QGsHLW), or view here:

```bash
@echo off
 
:list
title Pack Optimizer
 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set packCount=0
 
:: Read for folders
for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /a:d /b') do (
    set /a packCount=packCount+1
    set choicePath[!packCount!]=%%~fD
    set choiceName[!packCount!]=%%~nxD
)
 
echo Available packs:
echo.
 
:: Print list of files
for /l %%x in (1,1,!packCount!) do ( echo %%x] !choiceName[%%x]! )
echo =========================================
echo.
 
:: Retrieve User input
echo Select a pack:
set /p select=?
echo.
 
:: Exit on invalid choice
if %select% leq 0 (
    echo Invalid choice, stopping...
    echo.
    goto exitchoice
) else if %select% gtr %packCount% (
    echo Invalid choice, stopping...
    echo.
    goto exitchoice
)
 
:: Print out selected filename
echo You chose "!choiceName[%select%]!"
echo =========================================
 
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
 
:optimize
set packDir=!choicePath[%select%]!
set dateDir=zzzOPTDATES
set srcFileName=""
set srcFilePath=""
set filesTotal=0
set filesProcessed=0
set filesOptimized=0
 
:: Count all files in target dir
echo Counting input files...
for /r "%packDir%" %%D in (*.png) do ( (echo "%%D" | find /i "zzz" 1>nul) || set /a filesTotal=filesTotal+1 )
echo Found %filesTotal% input files.
echo.
 
:: Execute following on each png in dir
for /r "%packDir%" %%D in (*.png) do (
    :: test that for loop above works
    echo lol
    :: Only do so on files/folders without "zzz" in name
    (echo "%%D" | find /i "zzz" 1>nul) || (
        :: Input file name with extension
        set srcFileName=%%~nxD
        :: Input file with full path + name + extention
        set srcFilePath=%%~fD
        :: ^^^ with with everything up to pack folder removed
        set srcFileRelPath=!srcFilePath:%packDir%\=!
        :: Path of output text file
        set outFilePath=!srcFileRelPath!
        :: Replace \ with + to fix naming error
        set srcFileRelPath=!srcFileRelPath:\=+!
        :: Path of where to place last modified date text file, and what to name it
        set txtFilePath="%packDir%\%dateDir%"
        set txtFileName="!srcFileRelPath!.txt"
 
        title Pack Optimizer T:%filesTotal% P:%filesProcessed% O:%filesOptimized%
 
        if "!srcFileName!" == "" (
            echo File does not exist, stopping...
            goto exitchoice
        )
        if not exist "!srcFilePath!" (
            echo Path does not exist, stopping...
            goto exitchoice
        )
 
        :: Create text file folder if it doesn't exist
        if not exist "%packDir%"\%dateDir% mkdir "%packDir%"\%dateDir%
 
        :: Get contents of text file
        if exist !txtFilePath!\!txtFileName! (
            for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (!txtFilePath!\!txtFileName!) do set oldTime=%%x
        ) else (
            set oldTime=None
        )
 
        :: Get last modified date of current texture
        for %%? in ("!srcFilePath!") do set curTime=%%~t?
 
        if !oldTime! == !curTime! (
            echo !outFilePath! unmodified, skipping to next file...
            echo.
        ) else if "!oldTime!" == "EXCLUDE" (
            echo !outFilePath! excluded, skipping to next file...
            echo.
        ) else (
            echo !outFilePath! modified, optimizing...
            echo.
 
            :: Run each of these programs with high priority
 
            echo pngout...
            start /high /wait /b pngout "!srcFilePath!"
            echo.
 
            echo pngcrush...
            start /high /wait /b pngcrush -q -ow -rem allb -brute -reduce "!srcFilePath!"
            echo.
 
            start /high /wait /b deflopt "!srcFilePath!"
            echo.
 
            :: Set new time in text file after optimization
            for %%? in ("!srcFilePath!") do set newTime=%%~t?
            (echo !newTime!) > !txtFilePath!\!txtFileName!
 
            if exist !txtFilePath!\!txtFileName! (
                :: Increment files optimized counter
                set /a filesOptimized=filesOptimized+1
                echo wrote !txtFileName!
                echo with new time: !newTime!
                echo.
            ) else (
                echo ERROR: !txtFileName! not written, stopping...
                echo.
                goto exitchoice
            )
        )
 
        :: Increment files processed counter
        set /a filesProcessed=filesProcessed+1
    )
)
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
 
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
 
echo.
echo ==========================
echo.
echo           Done!
echo.
echo Optimized %filesOptimized% files of %filesProcessed%.
echo.
 
:exitchoice
echo Would you like to exit?
choice /c yn /m "Y = Exit, N = Return to list"
if errorlevel 2 (
    cls
    goto list
)
 
:end
exit
```

This is my first time using this site, please forgive me if this post isn't quite set up right.

Comment: Lines that start with `::` (double colon) cause problems in `for` commands and other places. Don't use they! Instead, use the `REM` command...

Comment: Also ```set varName=""``` will define a variable named `varName` with a value of `""`. The correct syntax should probably be ```set "varName="```, which ensures that there is no variable defined with the name `varName`. In fact the recommended syntax for defining variables is ```set "varName=varStringValue"```. Please before you continue trying to pursue issues, correct the entire script according to the above two comments.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! The script now works as intended!